# UITableView custom Cells, scrolling and memory management

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

So I have a table view that I am filling with custom table cells.  The problem I am running into is it starts to slow down while scrolling when lots of items start filling the table.  (I have implemented a dynamic scroll so as the user scrolls there is a method that goes out and fetches the next x items from the server so they can scroll to their heart's content without refreshing/pressing anything.)

Now I am creating the cells from a custom template I built in IB and initialize them something like this:

```
 CustomCellClass *cell = (CustomCellClass *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellNib owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (CustomCellClass *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

How should the memory management work in a case like this so I don't end up taking huge gobs of memory and slowing the scroll down?  Any help/suggestions/insight would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

EDIT:  I have checked for memory leaks so that shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So  I discovered a deep rooted memory leak in one of my data controller classes that is used to fetch the data.  THAT's what was causing the slowdown.  I saw the massive memory usage going on, but instruments wasn't detecting a leak.  Just goes to show nothing better then good old manual debugging.  :)  Thanks for the help.

Comment: was still good to brush up on the table cell mem management.  :)

Answer (score 1):

if the leaks tool doesn't show anything, sometimes it can be worth using the heap shot.
article on it here:
http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/

Answer (score 0):

The code fragment you've shown for managing table cells looks fine.

From your description, it sounds like the bottleneck is actual data retrieval from the server (web service?).  Are you making the web service call(s) on the main thread or a separate thread?  If you are not doing so already, perhaps you could call the web services on a separate thread and create "placeholder" cells that are refreshed later once the web service completes.  This should keep the UI responsive, though you wouldn't necessarily see the data in each cell immediately (e.g., it might say "loading" or something similar until the data is available).

Comment: Yeah I am doing it asynchronously so the UI doesn't freeze up.  It work well, but it gets kind of laggy when a lot of cells are loaded.  It's kind of strange though because if I drill in to a cell and then go back, the good performance comes back.  So I am kind of at a loss as to why it's happening...

Comment: You could add some NSLog calls to your CustomCellClass and watch init/deallocs to make sure that memory management for table cells is working as expected.  Once you get a screen full of cells, it should reuse cells from that point on (i.e., there shouldn't be init/dealloc as you scroll).  That would tell you whether the issue is with table cells, or elsewhere.

Comment: Yep, sometimes its tough to see a problem that's right in front of you until you try explaining it to someone else :-).